# Modal verb used for probability in german

Tags: translation, modal-verb

"Mag er mich?" is translated as " Does he like me?"
My question is does "Mögen" is used also for probability...
so my sentence about it I am confused "May she missunderstand me by that? " is translated into German as "Mag sie mich damit missverstehen?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in that `mögen` may be a modal that used to be used like the English `may` in the sense of probability and a full verb equivalent to the English `like`. Nowadays, the modal `mögen` is rarely used generically but mostly in fixed phrases like `Das mag so sein, aber …`.

So your translation is correct but would probably be understood by many people as *Does she like to misunderstand me?*. Unambigous translation would be

> Wird sie mich damit missverstehen?
>   Könnte sie mich damit missverstehen?

depending on the level of probability you're asking for.

Comment: It should be noted that "mögen" must not be used in the sense of "allowed to".

Comment: @Veredomon You're right. I'll adopt that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Another example is:

> Mag sein!
>
> Could be!

Look at *Bedeutung* number 1.a in the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/moegen).